# pulp pedia article deletion

Tags: blog, mediawiki, wiki

I hope this is the correct stackexchange subsite if not I apologise.

I would like to delete an article from PULP PEDIA, a horrifically rude and not funny website to mimic original wikipedia posts and enhance them with curse words.

Could somebody tell me how I can delete a PULP PEDIA entry without deleting the actual Wikipedia entry ?

Thank you very much.

All the best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Pulp Pedia](http://lohere.net/kulkapedia/samuel/Main_Page) is someone else's website. And you can't just delete articles from other people's websites, no matter how much do you dislike them.

After a little bit of investigation, I found out that the site automatically mirrors all pages of the English Wikipedia, in modified form (with added profanities and in ALL CAPS).

For example, look at [Pulp Pedia version of Wikipedia:Sandbox](http://lohere.net/kulkapedia/samuel/Wikipedia%3aSandbox) and compare it with [the original](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aSandbox). If you edit the original, the Pulp Pedia version will change immediately.

Because of this, there might be a chance how you could disable the whole Pulp Pedia, because [doing that is against Wikipedia's terms of service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aMirror#Remote_loading). So, if you contact Wikipedia (not sure who exactly is appropriate), there is a chance that they will ban them from accessing it.

Comment: They're also not properly complying with the attribution requirements in Wikipedia's license (CC-By-SA 3.0 / GFDL), and they may also be abusing Wikimedia trademarks (although they could fix both issues fairly easily by changing the footer on their pages). For the former, you could follow the [non-compliance process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aMirror#Non-compliance_process) listed on the page svick linked to above (as long as you've contributed some content to Wikipedia); for the latter, it may be best to [contact the WMF](http://wikimediafoundation.org/wiki/Contact_us) directly.

Comment: Ps. Looks like [it's been](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_talk:Jimbo_Wales/Archive_98#Is_this_an_infringement.3F) discussed [before](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Help_desk/Archives/2012_May_2#JANKO_KONSTANTINOV_ARCHITECT). You could also try bringing it up at the [Wikipedia admins' noticeboard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WP:AN); since the site is also loading Wikipedia's JavaScript, it would be easy for Wikipedia admins to black it out or otherwise disable it that way, should they want to.

Answer (score 1):

After a quick google, it looks to be manually, and badly, copied, not a bot or anything clever. If it's running wikimedia, try emptying or deleting the page, with the caveat that that could cause trouble by highlighting your concern/interest. If you own the media content on the page (images, mostly), you could try a DMCA request. If you have lawyers, you could get all evil-netizen and try going after them for libel. Only try this with *real* lawyers, that you pay *serious* money to.

However, the best thing to do is probably to ignore it. It's a satire site, and is very clearly a satire site. Don't take it seriously, and don't highlight your knowledge or attention about it. You do NOT want to kick off a streisand effect.

Comment: If the image is on Wikipedia, and Richard created it, then it's most likely licensed under a free license, so DMCA won't help here.

Comment: +1 for last sentiment. It's just some stupid site that gets no visitors, who the heck cares?